# I want to make a function in react js so that when I click on a Link tag, I set the 'to' path to a setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

[[Link][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoqPQ.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CopPx.png)
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ2Ms.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPoTE.png)

I tried to make a function to set product with setState and in the same time to set the route to product.strMeal(name). The problem is that when i click on the Link tag my route does not update.

```
<div className="category-container">
        {
            category.map(meal => {
                return (
                    isLoading ? <Loader /> : (
                        <Link onClick={() => getClickedProductCompleteInfo(meal.strMeal)} to={`/${product.strMeal}`}  className="meal-card" key={meal.idMeal}>
                            <h3>{meal.strMeal}</h3>
                            <img className='meal-thumbnail' src={meal.strMealThumb} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} alt="meal" />
                        </Link>
                    )
                )
            })
        }
    </div>

const getClickedProductCompleteInfo = async (meal: string) => {
    const productCompleteInfo = await getDataFromApi(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${meal}`);
    setProduct(productCompleteInfo.meals[0]);
}    


<Routes>
    <Route path="/" >
      <Route index element={<Home isLoading={isLoading} categories={categories} setCurrentCategory={setCurrentCategory} />} />
      <Route path={`categories/${currentCategory}`} element={<Category product={product} setProduct={setProduct} currentCategory={currentCategory} getDataFromApi={getDataFromApi} />} />
      <Route path={`${product.strMeal}`} element={<Product product={product}/>}/>
      <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
      <Route path='contact' element={<Contact />} />
      <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to="/"></Navigate>} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
```

Comment: Please include all code as properly formatted code snippets instead of images of text. Images are not accessible and can be more difficult to read. See also [mcve].

Comment: So i just edited and i format the code.

Comment: Which route is rendering the component that is rendering the link? Can you clarify what you mean by "The problem is that when i click on the Link tag my route does not update"? What are you expecting to update, something in the `Product` component? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: From what I can tell of the code it seems like you are wanting to fetch some data based on the link that was clicked. This is ***not*** what links are for and not the way they should be used. Fetching data should be an intentional side-effect of a React component reading the URL path and "extracting" an id value as a route path parameter and issuing the fetch in a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Thanks!!! I solved the problem, sorry i am begginer to this site. Thanks a lot!!!